# Logo and Navigation Over Rotating Banner

Tags: z-index, css-position, rotator

I've been trying to create a nav and logo div that sits over a rotating banner.  I'm having trouble with the CSS.

For example:

```
<div class="logo-div">

<div class="logo">
<img src="image/logo.jpg">
</div>

<div class="nav">
<ul><li>nav-button</li></ul>
</div>

</div><!--logo div -->

<div class="rotator">
</div>
```

I tried negative top margin to pull the rotator up into the nav-logo div but that only brought the nav up and not the logo.  I also tried switching the order of the nav-logo and rotator, but that didn't work either.

Guessing I need to play with z-index and relative and absolute positioning but I can't get it to work right.

Thanks very much.

Here's an example of a site with this feature: [website](http://cameronreynoldsflatt.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if your sample link is a proper indication of what you want...the key question would be what method are you going to use to rotate the banner? javascript of course (if you want cross-browser compatibility) but...what method?
The guy from the link you provided is using a `<ul>` element with several `<li>`'s inside it, each of which has one of the different backgrounds...

using `transitions` (advanced css3 effect), `absolute positioning` and `left`, he basically scrolls them horizontally changing the value of `left`

In any case, you'd need something like:

```
.wrapper {display:block; position:relative;}
.logo-div {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999;}
.logo {}
.nav {}
.rotator {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1;}
```

and the html should be something like:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="rotator">
      insert your magic slides of different content or backgrounds here, be in in ul+li format or just divs or whichever method you prefer
  </div><!-- .rotator -->

  <div class="logo-div">

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="image/logo.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <ul>
       <li>nav-button</li>
     </ul>
    </div><!-- .nav -->

  </div><!--logo div -->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->
```

The real question here is, again, what method will you use to cycle content? You can copy his method, or do a mere changing of background position if all you want to change is the background but not any content.

The .wrapper or parent elements need position:relative;
The contents of that wrapper, in this case .logo-div and and the .rotator would need position:relative
The .rotator div that goes behind the navbar and logo and all that needs z-index:1; plus top:0; and left:0; as an example
The .logo-div that goes above the .rotator div needs z-index:2 or 9999; plus top:0; and left:0; as an example

So now everything stays where it should and the contents of .rotator can move without messing up the rest of the page.

Choose a method to cycle/move the background content/images and I will give you a more specific answer.

Hope this helps